# How to get a role's name/ARN into its own AssumeRole policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've got a CloudFormation stack that creates several IAM roles. I have the somewhat unusual-sounding requirement to include a statement in the role's AssumeRole policy preventing the role from assuming itself. The role names are constructed using `Fn::Join` with the value of a  parameter, so in order to reproduce the role name and construct its ARN in the policy statement, I have to duplicate that expression.

Is there any way to cache the result of the expression so that I don't have to repeat it? There are several of these roles and each one has the same issue. Can I define a parameter whose default value includes the value of another parameter and reference that? Or can I use Fn:GetAtt inside the definition of a resource to access other attributes of the resource being defined (such as its name)?

If not, is there another solution besides repeating the name-construction expressions? This is something I would put in the `locals` block in Terraform...

Since this wound up not being possible, I ran this shell one-liner to update each role after creation, to prevent it from assuming itself:

```
aws iam update-assume-role-policy \
  --role-name "$role" \
  --policy-document file://<(
      aws iam get-role --role-name "$role" |
       jq '.Role | .Arn as $arn | .AssumeRolePolicyDocument | 
           .Statement+=[{"Effect": "Deny", 
                         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", 
                         "Principal": { "AWS": $arn }}]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to cache the result of the expression so that I don't have to repeat it?

Sadly, there is no such way in plain CloudFormation.

> Can I define a parameter whose default value includes the value of another parameter and reference that?

Unfortunately, parameters can't refer other parameters.

> Or can I use Fn:GetAtt inside the definition of a resource to access other attributes of the resource being defined (such as its name)?

You can't get any return values of a resource before it is fully constructed.

Having sad that, if you know the role name up-front, you could construct its ARN yourself. Role ARNs have [known format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-arns). However, you want be able to use it as a `Principal` in the same role, as **principles must be valid**. Thus, you can't use ARN of a role as a principle before it actually exists.

If you want to add ARN of a role to be its own `Principal`, you would have to construct a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudFormation. Thus, you first create your role normally, and then use the custom resource (in a form of lambda function) to update it's `Principal` element.

Also since you have to duplicate a lot of elements in your templates, a general solution to this is by means of [CloudFormation macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html).

Either way, it seems to me that because your requirements regarding templates are not normally supported out of the box, you will have to develop some custom resources and/or macros to fully satisfy them. With custom resources and macros you can basically achieve what ever you want, but it will require extra development.

Comment: You're saying that however I manage to get the role's own ARN string into its AssumeRolePolicyDocument, CF will fail to validate that because the ARN refers to a role that doesn't yet exist. Maybe it's time to give up on raw CF and write a CDK app for this.

Comment: @MarkReed Yes. But this will not change with CDK or terraform. This is how IAM works. It will not allow you to create a role with non-existing Principal. You have to do it in two stages. First you care a normal role, and then update its Principal. This maybe easier with CDK or terraform, then in CloudFormation though.

Comment: Yes, I understand the limitation. I was thinking that since CDK wraps the CF stack creation in an imperative language, I could more easily coordinate adjusting the ARP after the role is created within the same application. Otherwise I have to use a wholly separate script.

Comment: But I wound up just using a simple shell script to fix the roles up instead; see my edit to the question post.

Comment: @MarkReed Glad it worked out. I though that you want to have everything under CloudFormation control. In that case you can't use AWS CLI in it.

Comment: That is still the goal, but getting the updated policy in place was more urgent. Will circle back to getting the IAC right for future new accounts.